# good way to test `numpy.allclose` on a time series?

Tags: python, numpy, testing, time-series

I'm trying to test in Python whether a vector of recovered times is close to a vector of ground truth times. Let's ignore how we recover the times, it's not relevant to the question.

My first instinct was to use `numpy.allclose`, but unless I'm misunderstanding something, `allclose` is actually a bad fit here because of [how it works](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html).

Essentially you specify an absolute tolerance `atol` and relative tolerance `rtol`, along with your ground truth vector `b` and a comparison vector `a`, and `numpy.allclose` returns:

```
all(numpy.abs(a - b) <= atol + rtol * numpy.abs(b))
```

There's some nuance to what the actual function does as you can see in the
[source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.20.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2186-L2257) but the "pseudo-numpython" above from the docs gives you the basic idea.

The issue is that with any monotonically-increasing vector of positive values, like a time series, your tolerance actually will increase!

Take this series of times in seconds:

```
>>> times_true = array([0.01147392, 0.46244898, 0.78571429, 1.22238095, 1.74857143,
   2.30984127, 2.92777778, 3.57      , 4.16634921, 4.76809524])
>>> times_recovered = array([0.00944365, 0.46007857, 0.7838881 , 1.22103095, 1.74722143,
   2.30849127, 2.92642778, 3.56865   , 4.16499921, 4.76674524])
```

I want my times to be no more than a millisecond apart, plus or minus some wiggle room. This is basically the case for my example vectors.

```
>>> np.abs(times_recovered - times_true)
array([0.00203027, 0.00237041, 0.00182619, 0.00135   , 0.00135   ,
       0.00135   , 0.00135   , 0.00135   , 0.00135   , 0.00135   ])
```

since I want the values to be "roughly 1 msec apart", I specify `atol` to be `0.001` and my `rtol` to be `0.001`. My understanding of these terms right now is that `atol` is the absolute difference between each element of a and b, i.e., `np.abs(a - b)`, and that `rtol` is some additional "slop" tolerance we can add. (edit: changed how I defined the terms originally).

Now look at the what this gives me for the second term above:

```
>>> atol, rtol = 0.001, 0.001
>>> rtol * np.abs(times_true)
array([1.14739229e-05, 4.62448980e-04, 7.85714286e-04, 1.22238095e-03,
   1.74857143e-03, 2.30984127e-03, 2.92777778e-03, 3.57000000e-03,
   4.16634921e-03, 4.76809524e-03])
```

For this vector of times, we start out with a relative tolerance of `1.e-5` and finish with `1.e-3`, a two orders of magnitude difference. In other words, `allclose` will check whether the differences `np.abs(a - b)` are less than or equal to the following:

```
>>> atol + rtol * np.abs(times_true)
array([0.00201147, 0.00246245, 0.00278571, 0.00322238, 0.00374857,
       0.00430984, 0.00492778, 0.00557   , 0.00616635, 0.0067681 ])
```

This seems bad? I want my tolerance to be roughly the same at every point but it's clearly increasing. And the tolerance will only continue to increase as I get larger times in my vectors. It's also bad because for small times my tolerance will actually be smaller! Giving me false alarms.

It seems like what I should really do is just take `np.abs(times_recovered - times_true)` and ask whether any of the values are greater than the largest difference I'm willing to tolerate

```
>>> MAX_DIFF = 0.003
>>> assert not np.any(np.abs(times_recovered - times_true) > MAX_DIFF)
```

but if so then am I just completely understanding how `numpy.allclose` is supposed to work?
Any feedback from sage scientific Pythonistas would be appreciated

Comment: Why not just use a relative tolerance of 0?

Comment: "My understanding of these terms right now is that rtol is the tolerance for the relative difference, i.e., np.abs(a - b), and that atol is the absolute largest difference I'm willing to tolerate" - no, that's completely wrong. Look at their actual roles in the calculation.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I agree with you that it makes more sense to interpret `atol` the way I defined `rtol`. But regardless of what they mean, I will still face the same problem of the "total tolerance" increasing (where "total" = `atol + rtol * np.abs(b)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem you want `all` your (pointwise) errors to be `close` to zero.  So... just use `allclose` on the error timeseries and a zero vector (it broadcasts under the hood):

```
t_err = times_recovered - times_true
MAX_DIFF = 0.003
np.allclose(t_err, 0, rtol=0, atol=MAX_DIFF)
```

This is effectively the same as your `assert` statement (but don't use assert in production code, unless it's a test!) - your choice which you want to use.

Comment: Thank you. This is basically what I ended up doing, so accepting this answer.except I feel like `np.allclose` just adds cognitive overhead to anyone reading the unit tests

Comment: Apparently I can only edit commenst for five minutes. Meant to say: ...

I feel like `np.allclose` just makes it harder for anyone reading the unit tests to figure out what's going on so I just went with `assert np.all(np.abs(times_recovered - times_true) < MAX_DIFF)`

I think the issue is that `np.allclose` is mainly meant for equality comparisons that neglect floating point error and I'm trying to use it for something else